# Raise 404 if Flask catch-all route starts with prefix

Tags: python, flask

I am using the catch-all url pattern in my Flask route. I want the view to ignore (throw a 404 error) any path that starts with `/api`. How can I do this?

```
@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def index(path):
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Check if the path starts with the prefix, then abort if it does.

```
from flask import abort

if path.startswith('api'):
    abort(404)
```